# Bubble Sorting Routine

Tags: c

Hi I am newer to c language and When I compile the current code to find the variance I get the following error: expected expression before']' token var=var+pow((x[]-my_mean(n,double x[])),2);
    #include 
    #include 
    double my_var(int n, double x[]);
    double my_mean(int n, double x[]);
    double my_sum(int n, double x[]);

```
int main (void)
{
    int n=5;
double x[]={4, 6, 2, 7, 9};
    my_var(n,x);
    return 0;
}
double my_mean( int n , double x[])
{
    return my_sum(n, x)/ n;
}
double my_sum(int n , double x[])
{
    int i;
    double s=0;
    for( i= 0; i<n ;i++)
    {
        s = s + x[i];
    }
    return s;
}

double my_var(int n, double x[])
{
    double var;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        var=var+pow((x[]-my_mean(int n,double x[])),2);
    }
    return var;
}
```

Comment: The compiler told you anything you have to know to fix that. Did you try something at least?

Comment: Incidentally, in `my_var` I suspect you meant to calculate `my_mean` just once and store it in a variable to use in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Okk.. I have got something figured out with you code.. Have a look::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double my_var(int n, double x[]);
double my_mean(int n, double x[]); 
double my_sum(int n, double x[]);

int main (void)
{
    int n=5;
    double x[]={4, 6, 2, 7, 9};
    printf("%f",my_var(n,x));
    return 0;
}
double my_mean( int n , double x[])
{
    return my_sum(n, x)/ n;
}
double my_sum(int n , double x[])
{
    int i;
    double s=0;
    for( i= 0; i<n ;i++)
    {
        s = s + x[i];
    }
    return s;
}

double my_var(int n, double x[])
{
    double var=0;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        var=var+pow((x[i]-my_mean(n,x)),2);
    }
    return var;
}
```

Just added a print statement at the end of the `main` to check the result. In the for loop of your code in the function `double my_var(int n, double x[])`  you have a statement ::`var=var+pow((x[]-my_mean(int n,double x[])),2);`, firstly you cannot specify the data types in the function calls. Further, in the `pow` function you write `(x[]-my_mean(int n,double x[])),2`, instead of `x[]` it should be `x[i]`, you need to specify an index.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

and when you include math.h in your program then you have to compile it by the command "gcc my_program.c -o my_program -lm"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the loop index. Also, remove types from your call.

```
var=var+pow((x[i]-my_mean(n,x[i])),2);
```

Comment: The type of the second parameter for `my_mean` is an *array of* `double`, not `double` ;)